# fprintf and ctime without passing \n from ctime

Tags: c, file, text-files, printf, ctime

I have an issue with inserting time in a text file. I use the following code and i get `|21,43,1,3,10,5| Wed Feb 01 20:42:32 2012` which is normal but what i WANT TO DO is place the time before the numbers for example like `Wed Feb 01 20:42:32 2012  |21,43,1,3,10,5|` However, i cant do so cause when i use the fprintf with ctime function before fprintf the numbers it recognizes the \n within ctime and so it changes line 1st and then printing the numbers. It goes like:

```
    Wed Feb 01 20:42:32 2012
    |21,43,1,3,10,5|
```

which is something that i dont want... How can i fprintf the time without swiching to the next line in the text??? Thanks in advance!

```
fprintf(file,"   |");
    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        buffer[i]=(lucky_number=rand()%49+1);       //range 1-49
        for (j=0;j<i;j++)                           
        {
            if (buffer[j]==lucky_number)
                i--;
        }
        itoa (buffer[i],draw_No,10);
        fprintf(file,"%s",draw_No);
        if (i!=5)
            fprintf(file,",");
    }
    fprintf(file,"|     %s",ctime(&t));
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`strftime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) and [`localtime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime) to create a custom formatted string of your timestamp:

```
char s[1000];

time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm * p = localtime(&t);

strftime(s, sizeof s, "%A, %B %d %Y", p);

printf("%s\n", s);
```

The format string used by `ctime` is simply `"%c\n"`.

Comment: nice answer. I ll try that as well.

Comment: Nice! `strftime` allows very flexible approach for printing the time stamp in different formats!

Answer (score 13):

You can use `strtok()` to replace `\n` with `\0`. Here's a minimal working example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    char *ctime_no_newline;
    time_t tm = time(NULL);

    ctime_no_newline = strtok(ctime(&tm), "\n");
    printf("%s - [following text]\n", ctime_no_newline);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sat Jan  2 11:58:53 2016 - [following text]
```

Answer (score 11):

Just use %.19s :

```
struct timeb timebuf;
char *now;

ftime( &timebuf );
now = ctime( &timebuf.time );

/* Note that we're cutting "now" off after 19 characters to avoid the \n
that ctime() appends to the formatted time string.   */
snprintf(tstring, 30, "%.19s", now);  // Mon Jul 05 15:58:42
```

Comment: Printing 19 characters will leave off the year.  If you want to include the year, use `"%.24s"` instead.

Answer (score 9):

1. Copy the return of `ctime()` to a temporary string, remove the `'\n'` from that temporary string, then print the temporary string.
2. Print just the 1st 24 characters of the return from `ctime()` by using the (field width and) precision of the printf conversion.

Answer (score 8):

in c++11 you can do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

// Prints UTC timestamp
void printTime() {
    time_point<system_clock> now = system_clock::now();
    time_t now_time = system_clock::to_time_t(now);

    auto gmt_time = gmtime(&now_time);
    auto timestamp = std::put_time(gmt_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    cout << timestamp << endl;
}
```

**Output:**

> 2017-06-05 00:31:49

Comment: I'm surprised there's so few answers using `chrono`. Thanks Caner, that's brilliant.

Comment: Note that the order of `using namespace std; using namespace chrono;` matters. Reverse it, and it won't compile.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
char *p;
int len;

/* ... */

p = ctime(&t);
len = strlen(p);
fprintf(file,"|     %.*s", len - 1, p);
```

That way it only prints the string minus the last character (i.e. the `\n`).

Comment: or: printf("%.*s", (int)strlen(p)-1, p);

Answer (score 1):

I did this after obtaining the ctime string:

```
#include <string.h>
...
myctime[ strlen(myctime) - 1 ] = '\0';
```

This just overwrites the ctime carriage return with a string termination character, effectively terminating the string with two '\0' characters instead of one.  (It seems weird that ctime does that in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

Just copy 'length - 1' bytes to another string.

```
strncpy( newString, draw_No, strlen(draw_no) - 1 );
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to nul-terminate the string afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
    c_time_string = ctime(&current_time);
    len_of_new_line = strlen(c_time_string) - 1;
    c_time_string[len_of_new_line] = '\0';
```

What this will actually do is it replaces strlen - 1 char (new line char in this case) of ctime array with null-terminator character - it cuts out new line character from end '\n' and shorten array of 1 character.

If strlen was 25 before, after this it should be 24.